# mysql.format what should I change null variables to if I want to make it accept any value in the query

Tags: mysql, node.js, variables, null, format

I am trying to do a query with many different parameters but not all are necessary since it will act as a way to search through a database. I could just do this

```
if(req.query.Player1 === ''){
    var Player1 = " Player1 = " + "'" + req.query.Player1 + "'"; 
}
```

However, this is not very secure so I wanted to use mysql.format so it makes it more secure.

```
var sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM sg_vod_database.vod_data WHERE Player1 = ?", [Player1])
```

Here is the other option I have tried.
However if the value is null because they didn't enter anything, I want the query to accept all values for that item. If they don't care who the player is then it should be okay with any player. But I cannot find a way to make it so that the mysql.format will accept a variable that turns it to select all values. I had tried replacing it var Player1 with *, 1+1, Player1, and true but the format wraps it in single quotes by default so it is not very effective. If there is a way to maintain this and have it accept values or a different way to format it so it remains secure please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe you can predefine your query, and only set it when a user provides input. I'd say maybe you can try experimenting with "LIKE"

```
// untested
query = "%"

if(req.query.Player1){
    query = req.query.Player1
}

var sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM sg_vod_database.vod_data WHERE Player1 LIKE ?", [query])
```

P.S. I suggest you define the columns you want returned from your DB specifically rather than using asterisk(*), unless that was just for your question/example. Using asterisk makes the application unaware of schema changes.

EDIT: I hope I don't misunderstand the question. If the user does not provide input then the SQL would return all rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation on using LIKE, I think that will come in handy later. But I'm not sure if this will work as I want it. Basically, I have about 11 variables that they would be able to search through for more specifics since I'm building a site that is basically on an online database. And since they don't have to specify every variable to search I wanted to see if I could make a single query that would also cover the cases of them not inputting anything in certain fields by making it the equivalent of saying they want to see it with any value.

Comment: Maybe you have figurede it out, would something like this work?
`select * from vod_data where ? in (col1,col2,col3,...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
//If it's null, then set it the value to the same name as the column so it returns all values
if(Player1 === ''){
    Player1 = 'Player1'
}
//Else, wrap the name in " " so that it is correctly read in the query
else{
    Player1 = '"' + Player1 + '"'
}

if(Player2 === ''){
    Player2 = 'Player2';
}
else{
    Player2 = '"' + Player2 + '"'
}


var sql = mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM sg_vod_database.vod_data WHERE Player1 = ${Player1} AND Player2 = ${Player2}`)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).